# regular expression doesn´t work

Tags: jquery, regex, jquery-validate

Im trying to validate one textfield type password, but when im trying to write the password, the validation doesn´t work. For the validation: minlength 6, maxlength 12, uppercase, lowercase, and digits

HTML

```
<tr>
    <td>Contraseña *</td>
    <td>
        <input type="password" name="password1" id="password1">
    </td>
</tr>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
 $.validator.addMethod("password1", function (value, element) {
     return this.optional(element) || /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z]).{6,12}$/i.test(value);
 });

 $("#frmDatos").validate({
     errorContainer: contenedor,
     errorLabelContainer: $("ol", contenedor),
     wrapper: 'li',
     meta: "validate",
     rules: {
         password1: {
             required: true
         }
     },
     messages: {
         password1: "La contraseña no es válida"
     },
```

Comment: Do you mean that the password has to contain uppercase chars AND lowercase chars AND digits (in this case I would create multiple regexp's). If not @Cerbrus got it.

Comment: i mean a mixture, at least: a-z, A-Z, and digits (all required)

Comment: Please don't limit the password length! People are wanting to use passphrases that are much more secure.

Answer (score 6):

Try this instead:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,12}$/.test(value)
```

Regex parts:

```
# /           - Start regex
# ^           - Match the beginning of the string,
# [a-zA-Z0-9] - Followed by any character that's within the a-z, A-Z, or 0-9 range,
# {6,12}      - And there's between 6 and 12 of these characters,
# $           - Followed by the end of the string (So not followed by any other characters)
# /           - End regex.
```

When all 3 elements must be found in the PW, the easiest and possibly most **readable** thing to do would be:

```
$.validator.addMethod("password1", function (value, element) {
    return /^.{6,12}$/.test(value) && // The string is between 6-12 characters long,
                 /\d/.test(value) && // And contains a digit,
             /[A-Z]/.test(value) && // And contains a upper-case letter,
            /[a-z]/.test(value)    // And contains a lower-case letter.
});
```

The advantage of this is that, in case the string doesn't match the length requirement, the rest of the regexes won't be evaluated. It's a "Short Circuit" operator, meaning that, if the value left of the operator is `false`, the full operation can't be `true`, so the right side won't be evaluated.

Comment: It's _uppercase, lowercase, and digits_ and **not** _uppercase or lowercase or digits or any mixture of these three_

Comment: @Andreas: OP dint't mention if the PW __has to__ or __can__ contain these elements.

Comment: it must contain the 3 elements, at least once, sorry for my bad explication

Answer (score 1):

This one should do:

```
/^(?=\w{6,12}$)(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?\d).*/
```

for details on how it works go here

http://www.asiteaboutnothing.net/regex/regex-lookarounds.html

The one in this article is for a max length of 10 but converting it to 12 is straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("passcheck", function(value, element) {
     var upperCase= new RegExp('[A-Z]');
     var lowerCase= new RegExp('[a-z]');
     var numbers= new RegExp('[0-9]');
     return this.optional(element) || (value.match(upperCase) && value.match(lowerCase) && value.match(numbers) && value.length >=6 && value.length <=12);
}, "* Your password must be between 6 and 12 characters. It must contain a mixture of uppercase, lowercase, and digits");
rules:{
    password1: {
       required: true,
       passcheck: true
    }
},
```

Comment: Why are you using `new RegExp()` and `.match` instead of simple regex literals and `.test`?

Comment: Cerbus, i will try to change my method

Comment: @jal: just have a look at my answer. It uses exactly the same regexes, minus the temporary variables or other bad practices.